# Switch Case statement Using Class level Variable

Tags: java, switch-statement

How can I use a switch case statement using class level variable.

```
@Value("${user.name}")
private static final String userName = "xyz";

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String nn = "xyz";
  switch (nn) {
    case userName:
        System.out.println("It Works!!");

  }
}
```

In the above example I have a class level variable called "userName" which is retrieving the value from properties file. To use this field in switch case statement I have to make it final and assign a value but it's not executing the case statement. 
How can I use the class level variable in switch case statement?

Comment: Why do you have to make it `final`?

Comment: if I don't then i get a compilation error in case stating "case expressions must be constant 
 expressions"

Comment: OK, I get it. I didn't notice the variable name. Can you try printing the value of `userName` before the switch statement to check if its correctly set?

Answer (score 0):

In `case userName:` the expression (`userName`) has to be a (compile time) *constant expression*.

If `userName` is declared like this:

```
private static final String userName = "xyz";
```

then `userName` is a (compile time) constant expression.

But if a `String` variable such as `userName` not `final`, or if it has a blank initializer, or if it is initialized to the result of a method call ... or a few other things ... then it is not a (compile time) constant expression.

Read [JLS 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) for the full set of criteria for a constant expression.

---

> So how do I solve my problem? I am trying to resolve "Cognitive Complexity" sonar issue where I am running a for loop for a list of objects and setting a new object variable based on elements of for loop object. I don't want to use if else statement and that's why was trying to switch case statement until I ran into this problem.

Now we are getting to the *real* issue!!

What you need is something that is simpler than if/else chains but still works when the strings (e.g. words) are dynamic.  Switch statements won't work<sup>1</sup>.

Here is one idea:

```
private static HashMap<String, Something> map = new HashMap<>();
// populate map for each word.

// then
String word = ...
Something something = map.get(word);
if (something) {
    // use it.
}
```

The `Something` could be a custom object, or a functional object type .... so that you could populate the map with lambdas.

This approach more wordy than a (hypothetical) string `switch` statement but the performance should be roughly the same.  Whether it is more readable will depend on the context and who is reading the code.

On the other hand, it could be more appropriate to just ignore the Sonar warning.  Sonar is giving you *advice* on code quality based on some rather crude heuristics.  It doesn't understand the code, and it doesn't understand how people (programmers) think.

---

<sup>1 - ... unless you generated source code and compiled it at runtime.  You should avoid that kind of complexity unless it is really warranted.</sup>

Comment: so how do I solve my problem? I am trying to resolve "Cognitive Complexity" sonar issue where I am running a for loop for a list of objects and setting a new object variable based on elements of for loop object. I don't want to use if else statement and that's why was trying to switch case statement until I ran into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It won't execute your case statement because the value of your switch variable nn is "abcd" while inside your case variable userName its "xyz" it's looking for "abcd" case.